# When using ListPlot, if Joined->True and PlotMarkers -> {Automatic} then if PlotRange is smaller than the range of data, then I get mismatched markers

Tags: plotting

When using ListPlot, if I set Joined->True and also set PlotMarkers -> {Automatic}, then if the range of values I feed into PlotRange are smaller than the range of data I've fed into ListPlot (i.e. if not all data is shown in the plot), then I get color/style mismatched markers, as I will show with an example.

```
data1 = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}];
data2 = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}];

ListPlot[{data1, data2}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{Pi/6, 11 Pi/6
}, {-5/6, 5/6}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic}]
```

This code produces the following plot:

[image: plot produced by above code]

Note how the color of the 'endcap' markers (I don't know what else to call them) for the dataset data2 (yellow) is still blue and the shape is incorrect.

I would like to know how to manipulate these 'endcap' markers. Frist, how do I change these specific 'endcap' markers to match the color and style of the rest of the markers associated with that data set? Sdcond, how can I remove these 'endcap' markers.